# Dynamically populate onclick url link based on field from foreach loop - image gallery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, button, gallery

I have the following view in my mvc app

```
@model ProjectExplorer.Web.ViewModels.ProjectDetailViewModel
@{
}
<section id="imagery">
    <h3>Project Imagery</h3>
    @if (@Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages.Any())
    {
        <a href="@Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetProjectURL" target="_blank">Click here to find, share and download more digital assets</a>
    }
    <!-- The Bootstrap Image Gallery lightbox, should be a child element of the document body -->
    <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
        <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
        <div class="slides"></div>
        <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
        <div class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body next" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 400px;"></div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                            Previous
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href = '@Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetProjectURL';">
                            Info
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">
                            Next
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages.Any())
    {
        <div style="margin-top: 17px;">
            <div id="links">
                @foreach (var item in Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages)
                {
                    <a href="@item.URL" title="@item.FileName" data-gallery>
                        <img src="@item.Thumbnail" alt="@item.FileName" class="img-thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:7px;" />
                    </a>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <p>There are no images assigned to this project in OpenAsset.</p>
    }
    <div>
        @{
            var grid = new WebGrid(
                        canPage: false,
                        canSort: false,
                        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");

            grid.Bind(Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages, autoSortAndPage: false);

            @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
            fillEmptyRows: false,
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            columns: grid.Columns());
        }
    </div>
</section>
```

I want the below line to point to a field in my Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages class named InfoURL instead of the OpenAssetProjectURL.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href = '@Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetProjectURL';">
```

I am not sure how to dynamically set the url the button is pointing to based on a value from the foreach loop.

I have a image gallery (see link below) that I want to make the Info button point to a linked based on the picture that is being shown instead of a overall link like I have it in the above view code. 
[Image of the image gallery and button I am trying to set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbKDQ.png)
If it helps, I am using the blueimp gallery.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Hoping more information will help. When the page opens, it loads all the images into the page into the web grid. When the user clicks in the image, a modal opens and the user can click though the images. I have an info button that will link to another page that is unique per image.

Based on James' suggestions, this is the view currently. I also added visual output of the links i am wanting to use and the current value of i. Currently the output in the foreach loop is correct, but when the modal is opened, its still only picking up the first InfoURL.

```
@model ProjectExplorer.Web.ViewModels.ProjectDetailViewModel
@{
    int i = 0;
}
<section id="imagery">
    <h3>Project Imagery</h3>
    @if (@Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages.Any())
    {
        <a href="@Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetProjectURL" target="_blank">Click here to find, share and download more digital assets</a>
    }
    <!-- The Bootstrap Image Gallery lightbox, should be a child element of the document body -->
    <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
        <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
        <div class="slides"></div>
        <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
        <div class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body next" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 400px;"></div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                            Previous
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href = '@Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages[i].InfoURL'";>
                            Info
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">
                            Next
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages.Any())
    {
        <div style="margin-top: 17px;">
            <div id="links">
                @foreach (var item in Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages)
                {
                    <a href="@item.URL" title="@item.FileName" data-gallery>
                        <img src="@item.Thumbnail" alt="@item.FileName" class="img-thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:7px;" />
                    </a>
                    <p>@item.InfoURL</p>
                    <p>@i++</p>
                    i++;

                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <p>There are no images assigned to this project in OpenAsset.</p>
    }
    <div>
        @{
            var grid = new WebGrid(
                        canPage: false,
                        canSort: false,
                        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");

            grid.Bind(Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages, autoSortAndPage: false);

            @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
            fillEmptyRows: false,
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            columns: grid.Columns());
        }
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: @Courtney Ammons - is `InfoURL` value the same for value for every item in `Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages` and what is the type? If its the same you can use an index - e.g. `location.href = '@Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages[0].InfoURL'`

Comment: Or you could use `ViewBag` to sore the current `InfoURL`

Comment: @JamesP I was able to use the index option that you suggested. Worked great!
To answer the questions you asked, InfoURL is the field used in all images and is a string value. I used the exact code snipet you provided and it worked like a charm.

I am not sure how to mark comments as the answer to provide you credit for the answer.

Comment: @JamesP I just noticed it only looks for the first image in the list. When I pick a different image it is still using the InfoURL of the first image. How do I get it do pick up different InfoURL for each image?

Answer (score 0):

As above using `@Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages[0].InfoURL` will only bind to the first item in the collection - the item at position 0.

So you can declare a variable in your view `@{ int i = 0; }`

Then use this to access the required index:

```
@Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages[i].InfoURL
```

Then increment it as you loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.OpenAssetImagesVm.OpenAssetImages)
{
    <a href="@item.URL" title="@item.FileName" data-gallery>
       <img src="@item.Thumbnail" alt="@item.FileName" class="img-thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:7px;" />
    </a>
    @i++;
}
```

This will then match the index you need e.g 0 for the first item, 1 for the second etc.

Hope this makes sense? If not will explain in more depth tomorrow. Have run out of time now.

Comment: I may been more clarification. I made the changes you note above and it still is always pointing to the link from the first image. I added visual output for the current link and the output of i on the screen and that all seems to be functioning, but i that the modal is backing up seems to always been the initialize i of 0

It doesnt seem that when I click to bring up the modal, the new value of i is picked up

Comment: I'm not really clear on how the modal is being populated?